# C++ timer_create() does not create new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

What I am trying to achieve is to use a timer, which starts new thread each minute at exact the same time.
So far it did the job, but unfortunately if the thread execution delays more 1 min, then a new thread is NOT created and instead - the timer waits til the previous thread finishes and then executes the new one, which is not my aim.

How may I instruct the timer to fire a new thread every time, without waiting previous to finish?

What I used:

```
itimer.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
itimer.it_interval.tv_sec = 60;
itimer.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

tt = time(NULL);
tt += 60; //next minute
tm_t = localtime(&tt);
tm_t->tm_sec = 0;
time_t vv = mktime(tm_t);
itimer.it_value.tv_sec = vv;

memset (&sigev, 0, sizeof (struct sigevent));
sigev.sigev_value.sival_int = 666;
sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
sigev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
sigev.sigev_notify_function = threadFunction;

if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &timer) < 0){
    exit (errno);
}
if (timer_settime(timer, TIMER_ABSTIME, &itimer, NULL) < 0){
    exit (errno);
}
```

.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [`sigevent(7)`  manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) you will see that for `SIGEV_THREAD` the function is called "as if" it were the start function of a new thread. The system *may* start a new thread, or the system may use a *single thread* to handle *all* timer events (which fits your description), or something completely different altogether.

If you want to make sure a new thread is created unconditionally, then you should make a wrapper function that creates a thread, and make `sigev_notify_function` point to that wrapper function.

Comment: What you mean by "wrapper function" really?

Comment: @IvailoTanusheff The function you use for `sigev_notify_function` is a simple function which creates a thread using the *actual* thread function (`threadFunction` in your case). It's a function which "wraps" your actual function.